# Wpf changing Visibility from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to change the visiblity of my datagrid from code behind but it's not working

```
 private void afch_data_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (donne_compte.IsVisible) // this is a grid and It's visible
        {
           dgComptes.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; 
           //when I breakpoint here , I find that the datagrid visibilty   `property is still set to hidden  

        }
    }
```

EDIT 
here s my datagrid Xaml It's a simple one :

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgComptes" CanUserAddRows="False"   IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"  ItemsSource="{Binding ComCollection}"  RowHeaderWidth="0"  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="529.534,84.016,-390.033,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="Auto"  MaxHeight="200"  Width="395.429" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Background="#FFCFCFCF"  ColumnWidth="*" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Black" VerticalGridLinesBrush="Black" RowBackground="#FFCFCFCF" AreRowDetailsFrozen="True" Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyle2}" CellEditEnding="dataGrid1_CellEditEnding" CurrentCellChanged="dataGrid1_CurrentCellChanged" SelectionChanged="dataGrid1_SelectionChanged" AutoGeneratingColumn="dataGrid1_AutoGeneratingColumn" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >

                <DataGrid.Columns >

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="champ_supp2" >
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button x:Name="supprime" Content="Button" Width="30" Height="30" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle12}" Click="supprime_Click"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>


                    <DataGridTextColumn   Header="Id"  Binding="{Binding ID}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn   Header="Taille"  Binding="{Binding TAILLE}"  />
                    <DataGridTextColumn   Header="Client" Binding="{Binding CLIENT}"   />
                    <DataGridTextColumn   Header="D.arrivée" Binding="{Binding D_ARRIVEE}"   />
                    <DataGridTextColumn   Header="D.départ" Binding="{Binding D_DEPART}"   />

                </DataGrid.Columns>



            </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Is it a child of a parent control that is set to invisible ?

Comment: @PhilipStuyck The parent is Visible

Comment: Can you show the XAML of `dgComptes`? Also do you have any other place that is setting the visibility (Perhaps a binding or a style or a trigger)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain   I posted the xaml ,  and I m pretty sure there s nothing that can  change the visisbility

Comment: Download [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) and take a look at the visual tree. Maybe you can spot the issue.

Comment: Please also post the content of `DataGridStyle2`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I removed the style and the problem persisted so there no need to

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Disclaimer**

---

Setting Visibility works fine for `DataGrid`. Just checked and this should perfectly work:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Show DataGrid" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <DataGrid Visibility="Hidden"
        Grid.Row="1"
        x:Name="gridToHide">
    </DataGrid>

</Grid>
```

with code behind:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.gridToHide.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

**Solution**

---

The thing which might disallow/block from setting `Visibility` property of a `UIElement` is `Visibility` of the parent element. 
If parent element is *hidden* you can't make its ancestors visible. The value of `Visibility` will be changed but `IsVisible` will remain **`false`**.

To fix the problem you have to check logical tree of elements (parents) and search for the hidden element.

Comment: Btw if I do it through a storyboard it works perfectly

Comment: @user3621917 so then either `Style` or some behavior which is resetting `Visibility`.

Comment: I removed all the styles but sitll

Comment: @AnatoliiGabuza not working for me, i took breakpoint there , it  comes and return successfully. but there is no change on view. collapsed items are not visible